# KeyEvent on Dialog not consumed when closing in JavaFX

Tags: modal-dialog, javafx-8, key-events

I have a requirement to navigate a table when the user hits the ENTER key.  For this I have created an event filter similar to:

```
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyReleasedFilter = event -> {
    if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)) {
        previousPosition = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        //do my navigation
    }
}
```

I have run into an issue where JavaFX Modal Dialogs used during navigation of the table to indicate an error, cause issues with this filter.  If the user closed the dialog with the ENTER key, that event is trapped by my event filter on the parent stage.  I am not sure how to prevent that.  It is causing inconsistent navigation.

Here is a simple application that demonstrates the behavior:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Alert d = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    d.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
        if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)) {
            d.showAndWait();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I have noticed that the dialog is closed with the KEY_PRESSED event, and will not capture the KEY_RELEASED event.

I have tried adding an EVENT FILTER to the dialog (Button/DialogPane/Scene and even Stage) - none intercept the KEY_RELEASED event.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried using event.consume() on dialog.setOnHidden() but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is another reason to use the `KEY_RELEASED` event, then I would recommend switching to triggering on `KEY_PRESSED` for navigation as well and switch your `EventFilter` to an `EventHandler`. The example below will allow you to toggle the `Alert` on and off. When it's on, you'll notice that the button text doesn't change. When it's off, the button text will change. Take a look at how JavaFX constructs Event chains [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm) if you haven't already.

```
boolean error = false;
int i = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    final Alert d = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    d.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    Button err = new Button();
    err.setText("Error off");
    err.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, t ->
    {
        error = !error;
        if (error)
            err.setText("Error on");
        else
            err.setText("Error off");
    });

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");

    btn.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
    {
        if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)) {
            if (error)
            {
                d.showAndWait();
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                btn.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(btn, err), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the KEY_RELEASED so that commits happen correctly.  For some reason when I use KEY_PRESSED (I started with that) I end up no navigating as I would want.  I will give it a shot with event handler rather than filter and see if that fixes the issue with that.  But just changing to handler didn't.

Comment: I changed everything to use KEY_PRESSED rather than KEY_RELEASED and the editCommit seems to fire twice when I have an error and I will get two dialogs.  That is why I used KEY_RELEASED, as I don't get that behavior, but I do get the KEY_RELEASED dropping through.

Comment: I believe I have determined the cause of the editCommit issues and why they were being called twice.  I have fixed that and reverted to KEY_PRESSED and it seems to work.  It will require further testing.  But I think I am on the right track.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a hack that works - I really don't like it, so I am hoping that there is a better solution (a clean one) to solve this issue....

Basically, right before I open my dialog, I set a boolean so I know it's open.  Then in my event filter, kick out if that is set to true.

public class EventTester extends Application{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

private boolean modalWasShowing = false;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Alert d = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    d.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
        if(modalWasShowing){
            modalWasShowing=false;
            return;
        }
        if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB)) {
            modalWasShowing = true;
            d.showAndWait();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Please let me know if you know of a better way to handle this.